# MongoDB advanced query help

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have this document where I have voters array

I am given post id (999), reply id (123) and voter id (10)
How can I change the second voter's name from bob to tom?

Can this be done using csharp driver?

```
posts:
{
      _id: ObjectId("999"),
      title : "First post",
      "replies" :
      [
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("123"),
                "text" : "Great post",
                "votes" : 2,
                "voters":[
                              {
                                 id: 10,
                                 name:"bob"
                              },
                              {
                                 id: 11,
                                 name: "john"
                              }
                        ],
        }
      ] 
 }
```

**EDIT: I recomposed the question with better document structure.**

Classes: My code still has the original structure related class.
         For my new proposed structure, this is my classes will look like

```
public class Post
{
    public Post()
    {
        Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
        title = string.empty;
    }

    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public string title { get; set; }

    public List<Reply> replies { get; set; }

}

public class Reply
{
    public Reply()
    {
        Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
        text = string.empty;
        votes = 0;
    }

    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public int votes { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }

    public List<Voter> voters { get; set; }

}

public class Voter
{
    public Voter()
    {
        name = string.empty;
    }

    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Don't think you can do it with one update operation the way your document is structured ([the positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator) wouldn't work over two arrays). What does the reply_id (123) signify (since it's used for both replies)? If you're given voter ID 10, why do you want to change the second voter (11)?

Comment: cwb, I changed the doc structure. It should be easier now.

Comment: @user762196: your structure changes does not help, because of still two level arrays embedding(vouters within replies)

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew points out, you need to change the structure. Not knowing what other constraints you have on the querying I can't make a definite suggestion. However, if you change `replies` to a document instead of an array, with keys being the reply ID string, you could do (in the MongoDB shell):

```
db.test.update({_id: "999", 'replies.123.voters': { $elemMatch: {id: 10}}},
               {$set: {'replies.123.voters.$.name': "new_name"}})
```

This query should be easy to construct from your IDs in your C# driver.

For clarity, the restructured document would look something like:

```
{
    "_id" : "999",
    "replies" : {
        "123" : {
            "text" : "Great post",
            "voters" : [
                {
                    "id" : 10,
                    "name" : "bob"
                },
                {
                    "id" : 11,
                    "name" : "john"
                }
            ],
            "votes" : 2
        }
    },
    "title" : "First post"
}
```

If that doesn't work for you, tell us a bit more about your use case and maybe we can figure out what would work.

The other alternative is that you break out replies into their own collection, making each reply a document with a field to reference the parent post. In this case I suspect that might be the simplest solution and should have good performance with a sensible index.

Comment: cwb, how will you declare the C# class that will represent the post object? I am interested to see the diffence in the c# class for your structure and my structure.

Comment: Please show me the c# class that will be used for your structure to make replies a document instead of array. Thanks

Comment: Is your structure a valid structure? Replies will have multiple reply in it. Won't replies be an array at that point?

Comment: @user762196, I'm afraid I don't know any C#. If you post how the current class looks I might be able to figure out what it needs to change into.

Comment: It's valid if the reply IDs are different for each reply (which I assume they would be if they are IDs).

Comment: @user762196, just added a note to say it might be easier for you to put replies in their own collection.

Comment: @user762196 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1237/discussion-between-cwb-and-user762196)

Comment: To make the replies property serialize as a document instead of an array you could declare it as Dictionary<string, Reply> instead of List<Reply>. When you add a new entry to the replies Dictionary use reply.Id.ToString() as the key.